# Please help me re-open this valid question

Tags: discussion

[SharePoint Link Sharing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/296906/sharepoint-link-sharing/296907)

I've edited the original question to improve it. I feel this is an important question and should be re-opened.

Please cast your vote.